# ScalaFX. Live binding

Tags: scala, user-interface, binding, scalafx

I have a simple UI window with just one Text node, witch shows current time and binded to the model:

```
import model.Clock

import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.beans.property.StringProperty
import scalafx.geometry.Insets
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.layout.HBox
import scalafx.scene.text.Text
import scalafx.Includes._

object Main extends JFXApp {
    val clock = new Text()
    clock.textProperty().bind( new StringProperty(Clock.curTime) )

    stage = new PrimaryStage {
        onShowing = handle { Clock.startClock }
        title = "ScalaFX clock"
        scene = new Scene {
            content = new HBox {
                padding = Insets(50, 80, 50, 80)
                children = clock
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a model:

```
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

object Clock {
    var curTime = ""
    private lazy val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")

    def startClock = {
        /*A code, witch runs in another Thread and 
          changes curTime every 1 second skipped here.
          Only one change of curTime for simplicity.
        */

        curTime = dateFormat format new Date
    }
}
```

My problem is: the text node in UI doesn't change, when curTime variable change.

I guess it renderes once on stratup. How to make text node show new value of curTime every time, curTime changed?

Sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Clock.curTime` is just a variable whose value gets updated periodically - it's not an observed property, so nothing happens when it is changed. In particular, there's no link between that variable and your `Text` element's contents

What you have done is to initialize a `StringProperty` with that value - but since the property itself is never updated, neither is the label. I think what you wanted to do was to make `curTime` a `StringProperty` instead of just a `String`. Now, whenever you change that property's value, the `Text` element's value will change accordingly.

You should note that interactions with *JavaFX*/*ScalaFX* can only happen on the *JavaFX Application Thread*, so if you try updating `curTime` from a another thread, you're going to run into problems. One way to achieve that would be to pass the code that actually updates `curTime` to `Platform.runLater`.

However, a simpler approach is to use a timed *ScalaFX* event to update `curTime` periodically from within *JavaFX*/*ScalaFX*, as follows:

```
import model.Clock
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.geometry.Insets
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.layout.HBox
import scalafx.scene.text.Text
import scalafx.Includes._

object Main
extends JFXApp {

  val clock = new Text()

  // Clock.curTime is now a StringProperty, which we bind to clock's text.  Since clock is
  // created lazily, it starts the timer event, so we do not need startClock either.
  clock.text <== Clock.curTime

  // Create the stage & scene.
  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "ScalaFX clock"
    scene = new Scene {
      content = new HBox {
        padding = Insets(50, 80, 50, 80)
        children = clock
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In `Clock.scala`:

```
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import scalafx.animation.PauseTransition
import scalafx.application.Platform
import scalafx.beans.property.StringProperty
import scalafx.util.Duration
import scalafx.Includes._

// Object should be constructed lazily on the JFX App Thread. Verify that...
object Clock {
  assert(Platform.isFxApplicationThread)

  private val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")

  val curTime = new StringProperty(getDate())

  // Update the curTime property every second, using a timer.
  // Note: 1,000 ms = 1 sec
  val timer = new PauseTransition(Duration(1000))
  timer.onFinished = {_ =>
    curTime.value = getDate()
    timer.playFromStart() // Wait another second, or you can opt to finish instead.
  }

  // Start the timer.
  timer.play()

  private def getDate() = dateFormat.format(new Date())
}
```

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you very much!